# Why is a child component called four times on initial loading of the parent component?

Tags: angular, angular2-changedetection

I have a parent component and a child component. I know that change detection runs on events like HTTP request, `setInterval` or `setTimeOut` etc.

But here I don't have any of these events, and yet, when my parent component initially loads, the child component method `calledChildCompo()` is called four times.

Why is the change detection executed four times on initial load when I don't have events such as HTTP requests or any intervals?

### AppComponent (parent)

```
<app-change-det></app-change-det>
```

### ChangeDetComponent.html (child)

```
{{ calledChildCompo() }}
```

### ChangeDetComponent.ts (child)

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-change-det',
  templateUrl: './change-det.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./change-det.component.scss']
})
export class ChangeDetComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  calledChildCompo() {
    console.log('child compo is called');
  }

}
```

Comment: Please share your actual code for the two components. With the info provided it is impossible to know what could be the issue

Comment: Do you know the answer ? @OwenKelvin

Answer (score 1):

If you start your Angular app it will do an initial change detection cycle so that it knows all bound values and can render the page in the browser. For some reason, it actually executes two CD cycles on startup. (You could check it in the Angular source code, but I do not know the reason why.)

I suspect that you checked the number of CD cycles by running your app in dev mode. This explains why the number is 2*2 cycles. In dev mode, after each CD cycle there is an additional "check" cycle run, to check if any bound value changed during the actual change detection. If this is the case, the infamous `ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenChecked` error is thrown. This is to warn you that your model and view might be out of sync after the CD cycle. In prod mode, the additional cycle is skipped to have a better performance.

Comment: This answer makes the most sense.

Comment: "For some reason, it actually executes two CD cycles on startup. (You could check it in the Angular source code, but I do not know the reason why.)" I knew everything you said already except the one thing you say you don't know either, which is the thing I came here to know. So frustrating.

Answer (score -1):

Have a look at the below Demo with no child component or parent component [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-p97n6q)

What I have is simply

TS

```js
  ngOnInit() {
    console.log('Init')
  }
  testFunction() {
    console.log('TEST')
  }
```

HTML

```html
{{ testFunction() }}
```

If you look at the console You will see 4 logs with the word `TEST` but only 1 'init'. It simply a function working as expected, function reevaluates severally.

It is important to note that this reevaluation may cause your application to become slow. it is a bad idea to include functions in the html. Functions reevaluate for any slight change

### Explanation

> ## Angular’s Digest Cycle
>
> What you are seeing is the digest cycle at work. The digest cycle is how Angular’s auto-update magic works – it’s the reason that typing into an input box automatically updates anything that refers to its value.
> When the digest cycle runs, it effectively redraws everything that might have changed on the page.
> Angular uses some tricks to find “everything that might have changed”, and the main technique is watchers. These watchers are created automatically when you use directives like `ng-if` and `ng-class`, and when you use bindings like `{{ yourBindingHere }}`. 
> Each one of those things registers a watcher. When Angular’s digest cycle runs, every watcher is asked to update its state. In the case of ng-class, it will re-run the function bound to it, to see if anything needs to change. This is why your controller function runs multiple times, and it’ll run again each time something changes on the page.
> Source [Controller Function Is Executed Multiple Times](https://daveceddia.com/controller-function-executed-multiple-times/)

Comment: I know that, but i want to know the reason why if there is no change Detection it still runs four times instead one ?

Comment: @sdsd was this helpful?

Comment: Honestly Owen no,because the answer is about angularjs, and the CD is changed a lot during 1 version and 2+ version